# Add/remove class on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Problems with JavaScript add/remove class on button click. It just won't perform the function.

Read through a number of stack overflow solutions, none worked for this particular situation.

These are the elements:

```
// CSS 

.hideWelcome{
    display: none;
}

.autoHide {
    display: none;
}

// JavaScript Hide Welcome

  $(document).ready(function() {    
      $("#showFormBtn").live("click", function() {
        $("#WelcomeDiv").toggleClass("fadeOutUp animated hideWelcome");
        $("#formInput").toggleClass("autoHide");
    });
 });


    // Welcome Div

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="WelcomeDiv" class="one-half column fadeInUp animated" style="margin-top: 25%">
                <h4>Make a Difference</h4>
                <p>Volunteer today!</p>
                <div class="bounceIn animated">
                <input type="button" id="showFormBtn" name="showFormBtn" class="button button-primary" value="Sign Up"/>
                </div>
            </div>

    // Div to show

            <div id="formInput" class="one-half column fadeInUp animated autoHide" style="margin-top: 25%">
                <h4>HELLO YA'LL</h4>
                <p>Howdy!</p>
                <div class="bounceIn animated">
                    <input type="button" id="showFormBtn" name="showFormBtn" class="button button-primary" value="Sign Up"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers.

Try this:

```js
$("#showFormBtn").on("click", function() {
  $("#WelcomeDiv").toggleClass("fadeOutUp animated hideWelcome");
  $("#formInput").toggleClass("autoHide");
});
```