# javascript replace a div's class with another class

Tags: javascript, css

I have an HTML page with a div and a CSS class attached to it.
I want the class element attached to it, to be replaced with another class when pressed a button.
And most **importantly** I don't want a single line of CSS property to be changed of that class, **I want the entire class to be replaced by another class.**

*Can it be done?*

Sorry if this is already answered, I just couldn't find what I was looking for.
Here's the little code snippet of the HTML and the CSS:

```css
.class1{
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.class2{
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <button>Click</button>
 <div class="class1"><p>Hello Everyone</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(i want the class: *class1* to be replaced with *class2* on button click with the help of javascript.)

Comment: Yes, it can be done. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can simply google how to replace a class attribute!! Good Luck:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add/remove class on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306772/add-remove-class-on-button-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var box = document.getElementById('box');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  box.classList.remove('class1');
  box.classList.add('class2');
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.class2 {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<div id="box" class="class1">
  <p>Hello Everyone</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man you saved the day ! new to javacript, couldn't even think of something so easy

Answer (score 1):

Use `classList` to `remove` and add `classes` from elements.

```js
function a() {
var ele=document.querySelector('#a');
  ele.classList.remove('class1');
  ele.classList.add('class2');
}
```

```css
.class1 {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.class2 {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="a()">Click</button>
  <div id="a" class="class1">
    <p>Hello Everyone</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a click event listener to your button if you give it an `id`, and then change **all** elements with the class `class1` to class2`by using a`forEach` loop.

This way, if you have multiple elements with the class of `class1` it will change all of them, not just one of them.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", _ => {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName("class1")].forEach(elem => {
    elem.classList.remove("class1");
    elem.classList.add("class2");
  });
})
```

```css
.class1 {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.class2 {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<div class="class1">
  <p>Hello Everyone</p>
</div>
```

If you're after toggling between two classes you can use this little piece of code:

```
const index_b = elem.classList.contains("class1");
elem.classList.remove(classes[+!index_b]);
elem.classList.add(classes[+index_b]);
```

The above will toggle between two classes in the array called `classes`, which allows you to continuously click your button to change between the two.

```js
const classes = ["class1", "class2"];
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", _ => {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")].forEach(elem => {
    const index_b = elem.classList.contains(classes[0]);
    elem.classList.remove(classes[+!index_b]);
    elem.classList.add(classes[+index_b]);
  });
})
```

```css
.class1 {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.class2 {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<div class="class1 toggle">
  <p>Hello Everyone</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
   <style>
    .class1 {
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 150px;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .class2 {
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 200px;
        color: black;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
<script>
    function changeclass() {

        let div = document.getElementsByClassName("class1")[0];

        //or Use by Id

        let div = document.getElementById("class1");
        div.setAttribute("class", "class2");
    }
</script>
<button onclick="changeclass();">Click</button>
<div id="class1" class="class1"><p>Hello Everyone</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use .replace() property.

```
document.getElementById('test').classList.replace('class1', 'class2');
```